# Bootstrap Nav Collapse (Navigation) scroll - need to hide overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm continuing development with my website and I have now reached another problem.

When the nav bar collapses on smaller screens, there appears to be a scroll bar to suggest that there is overflow of the elements.

I tried to use the `overflow:hidden` property to remove this problem in CSS, but it doesn't appear to work properly.

See the screenshot and the code snippet below to see the problem.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'montserratlight';
    src: url('montserrat-light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('montserrat-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('montserrat-light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('montserrat-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('montserrat-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('montserrat-light-webfont.svg#montserratlight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'montserratsemi_bold';
    src: url('montserrat-semibold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('montserrat-semibold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('montserrat-semibold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('montserrat-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('montserrat-semibold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('montserrat-semibold-webfont.svg#montserratsemi_bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
#header {
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .navbar-brand {
        display: none;
    }
}
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-family: "montserratlight";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
img.logoEmpreus {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
img.logoEmpreus:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: rubberBand;
    animation-name: rubberBand;
}
#page {
    margin: 0px auto;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 -1px;
}
li a {
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
li a:hover {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none
}
li.active a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none
}
ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: "montserratlight";
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.active {
    font-family: 'montserratsemi_bold';
}
.imageInside {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    /* for IE 6 */
}
h2 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
h2 span {
    color: white;
    font: bold 0.8em 'montserratsemi_bold', Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* fallback color */
    
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#base ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "montserratlight";
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <title>Problems | Stack Overflow</title>
   <!-- Tab Title -->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id = "header">
      <!-- Empreus logo Image. Animated. Width 300px. -->
      <img class = "logoEmpreus animated" src = "http://bit.ly/1P2ZlbH" alt="Empreus" width="300" />
   </div>
   <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
         <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
         <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Stack Overflow</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" class="active"><b>The Problem</b></a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </nav>
      <div class = "row">
         <!-- Declaration of First Row -->
         <div class="imageHolder col-md-12" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <!-- Image Container as DIV -->
            <div class = "imageInside hvr-underline-from-center" >
               <h2><span>Logo Issue.</span></h2>
               <img id = "imageHomeJPG" src="http://bit.ly/1P2Ylo3" style="width:100%" />
            </div>
            <!-- Image Link -->
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div id = "base" class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:10px">
            <p>
            <ul class="col-md-12">
               <!-- MAIN NENU BAR -->
               <li><a href="#">Copyright Whatever</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Unordered lists.-->
            </p>
         </div>
         <!-- Navigation HTML Markup -->
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Image showing the overflow scroll bar]

How can this scroll bar be removed?

Comment: Try `overflow-x: hidden;`

Comment: @mariocatch for which class?

Comment: I'm on mobile, check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552388/twitter-bootstrap-navbar-menu-scrolling

Comment: @mariocatch got it! I'll respond to my own question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, this question is easier to answer then it seems. 

In Bootstrap, there is indeed the `overflow - x` property enabled by default in the `bootstrap.css` file.

```
.navbar-collapse {
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
overflow-x: visible;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
border-top: 1px solid transparent;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}
```

To solve this problem, a simple property change is needed. 
`Overflow-x:hidden`

So no more scroll on the collapsed navbar!

Answer (score 1):

This CSS rule is causing your overflow.

```
li {
  display:inline;
  margin:0 -1px;
}
```

Remove it and simply target your elements with specific selectors. Now you menu will remain aligned on mobile and your hover property regarding the color blue work.

See working example Snippet.

```css
#header {
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}
#header .logoEmpreus {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#header .logoEmpreus:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: rubberBand;
  animation-name: rubberBand;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    display: none;
  }
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-family: "montserratlight";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "montserratlight";
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav .active {
  font-family: 'montserratsemi_bold';
}
.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-nav li.active a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="header">
  <!-- Empreus logo Image. Animated. Width 300px. -->
  <img class="logoEmpreus animated" src="http://bit.ly/1P2ZlbH" alt="Empreus" width="300" />
</div>

<div class="container">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Stack Overflow</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="active"><b>The Problem</b></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </nav>

</div>
```